# How is the theory of modular representation involved with error-correction?

Tags: error-correction

Recently, I have heard that the theory of modular representation can be involved with error correction in quantum information theory. However, from a point of view of mathematician, I am still quite unclear how modular representations can be used in error correction, could anyone here give some explanation? Some good references will also be helpful.

Comment: Have you seen it in classical error correcting codes?